# quickbooks online interaction

Tags: integration, quickbooks-online

I have a web app that I need to communicate with quickbooks online edition.  I am able connect and receive data.  The problem is is that the responce back that i get is not in a xml format or even better would be in json formate.  How can I get it to respond back in one of those formats?  Here is my code:

```
function request($xml, $certificate = null, $debug = false){
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    $header[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-qbxml'; 
    $header[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($xml); 

    $params = array();
    $params[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $header; 
    $params[CURLOPT_POST] = true; 
    $params[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = true; 
    $params[CURLOPT_URL] = $this->gateway; 
    $params[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT] = 30; 
    $params[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $xml; 
    $params[CURLOPT_VERBOSE] = $debug; 
    $params[CURLOPT_HEADER] = true;

    // This is only for the HOSTED security model
    if (file_exists($certificate))
    {
        $params[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false; 
        $params[CURLOPT_SSLCERT] = $certificate; 
    }

    // Some Windows servers will fail with SSL errors unless we turn this off
    $params[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
    $params[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 0;        

    // Diagnostic information: https://merchantaccount.quickbooks.com/j/diag/http
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, '<myipaddress>');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $params);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) 
    {
        $errnum = curl_errno($ch);
        $errmsg = curl_error($ch);

        _log('CURL error: ' . $errnum . ': ' . $errmsg, $debug);

        return false;
    } 

    // Close the connection 
    @curl_close($ch);

    // Remove the HTTP headers from the response
    $pos = strpos($response, "\r\n\r\n");
    $response = ltrim(substr($response, $pos));

    return $response;       
}
function item_list(){

    $xml = 
        '<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <?qbxml version="6.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <SignonMsgsRq>
                <SignonTicketRq>
                    <ClientDateTime>' . date('Y-m-d') . 'T' . date('H:i:s') . '</ClientDateTime>
                    <SessionTicket>' . $this->session . '</SessionTicket>
                    <Language>English</Language>
                    <AppID>' . $this->application_id . '</AppID>
                    <AppVer>1</AppVer>
                </SignonTicketRq>
            </SignonMsgsRq>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <ItemQueryRq> 
                    <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
                </ItemQueryRq>

            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';
        $response = $this->request($xml, null, true);
        echo $response;

}
```

Thanks

Here my xml request:
    $xml = 
    '
    
    
        
            
                ' . date('Y-m-d') . 'T' . date('H:i:s') . '
                ' . $this->session . '
                English
                ' . $this->application_id . '
                1
            
        
        
             
                0

```
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>';
```

Here is my responce:

2013-04-12T12:28:11 V1-115-Q03kydq32h22tnfqnd5izf:689712285 1 2013-04-10T06:02:40 2013-04-10T06:02:40 0 Sales Sales 0 0 1 Sales 2 2013-04-10T21:20:43 2013-04-10T21:20:43 0 test product test product 0 0 1 Sales

Comment: What *is* the response you get back? It *should* be in XML format. Post your XML request and XML response.

Comment: this is the response i get back: 2013-04-12T12:28:11 V1-115-Q03kydq32h22tnfqnd5izf:689712285 1 2013-04-10T06:02:40 2013-04-10T06:02:40 0 Sales Sales 0 0 1 Sales 2 2013-04-10T21:20:43 2013-04-10T21:20:43 0 test product test product 0 0 1 Sales

Comment: Above in the post I tried to paste the xml but it looks like it is messed up.  But the function item_list() shows the xml i am using for the request.

Answer (score 2):

My stupid mistake.  I was echoing my result to browser which interpreted xml tags as html tags.  I used $xml = simplexml_load_string($response); print_r($xml); to view response in browser.